# Bash grep mac address unix/linux with semicolon

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, mac-address

why does not this work, shouldnt this output 30:84:A9:9B:2A:67 from my textfile?

```
grep [A-F0-9]\:{5}[A-F0-9] textfile.txt
```

Comment: I suspect it's instead matching something like `A:::::3`

Comment: how can i then add the ":" then?

Comment: grep [A-F0-9]\:[A-F0-9]\:[A-F0-9]\:[A-F0-9]\:[A-F0-9]\:[A-F0-9] textfile.txt. This seem so unnecessary...

Comment: `grep -i '^([A-F0-9]{2}:){5}[A-F0-9]{2}$' textfile.txt`

Comment: why the -i there? could u explain the code abit?

Comment: @anubhava Why you escaping `:`

Comment: Yes no need to escape `:`. `-i` so that it also matches lowercase MAC address

Comment: Ahh, i see. nice one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$ echo 30:84:A9:9B:2A:67  | grep -P "([A-F0-9]{2}:){5}[A-F0-9]{2}"
30:84:A9:9B:2A:67
```

Comment: `-P` is for perl-compatible regular expression. It is not working for me without it.

Comment: @moody Could also use -E, both allow the use of unescaped brackets. You could rewrite as `grep "\([A-F0-9]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[A-F0-9]\{2\}"` with no flags using BRE.

Comment: haha yeah i tested it, but why does it not work without it, just like to understand why/how things work.

Comment: @123 that one worked aswell, even better without flags. thanks dude.

Comment: I prefer less backslashes. ;) And most programming languages support perl regexes so guess it is easier to maintain.

Comment: @Timo BRE is far more portable, so probably easier to maintain without PCRE, you could also use ERE for this with no backslashes needed, which again is more portable.

Answer (score 0):

In your question "[A-F0-9]:{5}" was trying to match an alpha numeric character plus colon five times: X:X:X:X:X:

Also, grep accepts basic regular expressions (BRE) so you need to escape brackets and parenthesis.